# getTitle,getDescription,createPendingIntent(), getLargeIcon() missing in Playback Notifications with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to implement [Playback Notifications with ExoPlayer](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b). But getTitle,getDescription,createPendingIntent(), getLargeIcon are missing and android studio is showing red (Cannot resolve method). How can i get these?

I wrote my code exactly same as the link. I tried it multiple times.

This is my build.gradle file (if required):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mediaplayertest"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the gradle implementation correctly.

From [The hello world example](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.X.X'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.X.X'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.X.X'
```

In your gradle build script you have asked for the just "exoplayer"

NOTE: that for the PlaybackNotificationManager class you will need **exoplayer-ui** meaning for that particular class you would just need
 `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.5'` but I would also include **exoplayer-core**